# In DDD application layer service name for aggregate should be plural or singular?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In DDD, I am creating a service for each Aggregate in Application layer and aggregate name is added before service. Service purpose is to provide CRUD operations and also calling any domain related functionalities on aggregate in Domain layer.

Should such application service name include aggregate name as plural or singular e.g. `ProductService` or `ProductsService`?

Comment: Traditionally singular, but is it that important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singular most of the time. See also this post:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural

But, I would add that plural is reasonable when your particular Aggregate represents a whole collection.

Comment: yes plural makes sense as aggregate represents collection.

Comment: @Shifatullah don't forget that your Services should be named after actions (verbs) as well.
For e.g.:  ContractsCreation

Answer (score 3):

when creating some service provider that provides some services to other objects use singular name and be more concrete in naming, your ProductService name do not express what object used for. for example make services named ProductPriceCalculator or ProductShippingInfoValidator this are services and should have single responsibility (purpose)

Comment: ProductService does make sense, and it also respects the SRP as its sole purpose is to handle Product related operations. I think that is where most people fail to draw the line of what a Single Responsibility Principle means. It is easier to think of it as one and only one reason to change (n.r when anything related to a product changes). Also regarding the name of the class, always think of its scope: Higher scope, shorter name (as it is more generic), lower scope (longer name) as it is more concrete.